# CSS. Prevent table row to expand table

Tags: css

I have table with two rows: header and content. I need header to be the same width as content. If header text too long it should be truncate with ellipsis. I don't know width in pixel, and can't change table layout (only rows, or better only header). If it possible, how can I get result like below, using only styles for header row?

[image]

Comment: Using JavaScript is possible, but I still don't know the answer. Can anyone help? P.S. I can't calc width in runtime, maybe it's strange, but just trust me)

Comment: One problem is that you say you can't change the table layout, but you never mentioned what from. So I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/t8bnfr9s/), but the chances of the table layout being the same as yours are very small, of course.